# Devolucion de Json con estructura vacia para DataTable

Tags: json, visual-studio, api, vb.net

Tengo una api que retorna información, todo bien; mi problema es cuando no existe datos, me retorna un Json vacío [], y yo lo que hago al recibir dicho Json es convertirlo a un DataTable , entonces es ahi cuando obtengo errores, ya que logicamente no hay estructura para recrear mi DataTable.

```
Public Function PostHttpClienteSyn(EndPoint As String, data As Object, Optional EsTabla As Boolean = True) As Object
    Dim objResultado As Object
    Dim url As String = Path.Combine(oBenetton.UrlBase, EndPoint)
    Dim informacion = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
    Dim contenido As StringContent = New StringContent(informacion, Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    Dim httpRpta = HttpCliente.PostAsync(url, contenido).Result
    Dim Resultado = httpRpta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result

    If httpRpta.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
        If EsTabla Then
            objResultado = CType(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Resultado, GetType(DataTable)), DataTable)
        Else
            objResultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)(Resultado)
        End If
    Else
        Dim json = Linq.JObject.Parse(Resultado)
        Throw New Exception(json("message"))
    End If

    Return objResultado
End Function
```

Alguna idea de que podría hacer en estos casos? Lo que quiero es que me regrese una estructura del modelo de clase, para poder crear mi datatable sin registros. Aquí la linea con la que genero mi datatable:

objResultado = CType(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Resultado, GetType(DataTable)), DataTable)

Aquí la api que se encarga de responder la solicitud. Existe alguna forma de enviar este "accesorio" con su estructura? asi no existan datos?

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("AccesorioAsignado")]
    public dynamic AccesorioAsignado(int inventario)
    {
        IEnumerable<InventaAccesorio> accesorio;

        try
        {
            var consultaBenetton = new Inventarios(_contextoBenneton);
            accesorio = consultaBenetton.AccesorioAsignado(inventario);

            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, accesorio);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, new { message = ex.Message, datos = "" });
        }
    }
```

Gracias.

Comment: sip, metelo en un try catch... y si tira error, hace lo que te convenga...

Comment: Pero no sale error, si no que llega una estructura vacia, yo lo que quiero es que regrese la estructura del modelo de clase, para crear mi datatable sin registros.

Comment: A ver.. todo lo que me estas diciendo, es simplemente refactorizar tu codigo.. si viene vacia, como esperas crear algo de algo vacio? deberias tener en algun lado, la estructura vacia... para poder crear tu dt vacio...

Comment: Existe alguna forma de enviar este "accesorio" con la estructura? auque no existan datos?

        [HttpGet]
        public dynamic AccesorioAsignado(int inventario)
        {
            IEnumerable<InventaAccesorio> accesorio;
            try
            {
                accesorio = consultaBenetton.AccesorioAsignado(inventario);
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, accesorio);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, new { message = ex.Message, datos = "" });
        }

Comment: objects.. dynamic.. todo suena muy complejo.. porque tratas de hacer todo esto???

Answer (score 0):

utilizando DefaultIfEmpty resulta, aunque termino con un registro vacío, pero ya veré como manejo esa situación.

```
        try
        {
            var consultaBenetton = new Inventarios(_contextoBenneton);
            accesorio = consultaBenetton.AccesorioAsignado(inventario);
            accesorio = accesorio.DefaultIfEmpty(new InventaAccesorio { });
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, accesorio);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, new { message = ex.Message, datos = "" });
        }
```